# Introducing and removing new variables in First-Order languages with equality

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I am puzzled by something regarding variables and equality. Suppose you are in set theory and you know what $x \in A$. Intuitively, we know that this must entail that $\exists y \, (x \in y \wedge y=A)$, right? But how do we prove it? I tried. And here's what I could think.

Basically, I had to introduce some variable $z$ and assume (that's the key word) $z=A$. Then, it was pretty straightforward to derive
$x \in z$
$(x \in z \wedge z=A)$
and use existential generalisation to conclude $\exists y \, (x \in y \wedge y=A)$.

However, by the deduction theorem, I have a feeling that all I have proved is $z=A \rightarrow \exists y \, (x \in y \wedge y=A)$

What is the theoretical tool that lets me get rid of $z=A$ and take the consequence as a general fact? Am I allowed to just write $z=A$ in a proof without considering it an assumption? And if so, I wouldn't know which axiom would let me do that.

Comment: The general variable $z=A$ implies that $A$ exists, other way to say it is: for $y=A$ we have $(x\in y\land y=A)$ hence $\exists y(x\in y\land y=A)\,■$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x \in A$ --- premise

$A=A$ --- equality axiom

$(x \in A \land A=A)$ --- conjunction-introduction

$\exists y \ (x \in y \land y=A)$ --- $\exists$-introduction.

---

The [$\exists$-introduction](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7) rule is:

> $\phi [y/a] ⊢ ∃y \ \phi$,

where $\phi [y/a]$ denotes the operation of substitution, that is, of replacing all free occurrences of $y$ in $\phi$ with a parameter $a$.

In our case, we have $(x \in y \land y=A)$ as $\phi$ and $(x \in A \land A=A)$ as $\phi [y/A]$.

Comment: Is the application of the existential quantifier on line 4 correct? I don't think it is because it is not replacing all free instances.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist - yes, it.is. Typical example: $0=0 \vdash \exists x (x=0)$.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist - I had the same doubt and I realised you need to see it "backwards". The existential introduction is applied to a formula $\alpha$ where all the instances of $y$ have been replaced with $A$ and "returns" $\exists y \, \alpha$. The formula $\alpha$ we are talking about in this case is $(x \in y \wedge y=A)$. If you substitute A for y, you get exactly line 3. Therefore, from 3, you can deduce 4. This is a crucial fact that Mauro made me aware of.